# Twitterbot for mirroring blocked content - API endpoint problem?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, twitter

with the help of chatgpt I layman with really zero programming knowledge (only some HTML) tried to code a Twitterbot for over 10h but failed. I have now twitter api data, AWS api data and even already uploaded the python script. But then an api endpoint error (or something) comes up and it seems my function is not included in the free twitter develeper version. AWS console alert therefore was:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tweepy/binder.py", line 234, in execute
    raise TweepError(error_msg, resp, api_code=api_error_code)
tweepy.error.TweepError: [{'message': 'You currently have access to a subset of Twitter API v2 endpoints and limited v1.1 endpoints (e.g. media post, oauth) only. If you need access to this endpoint, you may need a different access level. You can learn more here: https://developer.twitter.com/en/portal/product', 'code': 453}]
```

Ai cant help anymore :(

So i ask you guys if the project is still feasible at all?

Basically, all I want is the following: All content from the Twitteraccount @KimDotcom should mirror a bot as @KimDotcomMirror (text, image, video, ..), just like copied by my own hand. This way, people can read and follow this user who has blocked them. Because I would like to do that and only in this way it seems possible.

In the process, small obstacles appear like: How to treat replies to other tweets?

---

Here is a conceptual summary of the bot model:

The bot (Twitter account X) checks every 30 seconds whether Twitter account "K" (@KimDotcom) has posted either a regular tweet (REG), a retweet (RET), a quote tweet (ZT) or a reply.

If "K" has published a regular tweet (REG):

- The content of the tweet (text, media) is stored in an "AWS cache" (if the respective file is smaller than 500mb!).
- A new tweet is composed in account "X", and the text of the tweet from "K" is pasted, along with the media from the "AWS cache".
- The tweet is posted and marked as "DONE."

If "K" has posted a retweet (RET):

- The retweet is retweeted normally to account "X".

If "K" posted a quote tweet (ZT) from another user:

- The user's original tweet is posted as a quote tweet to account "X", with "K"'s content added.

If "K" has replied to another user (Z):

- The content of "K" is treated as in the regular tweet and posted as a reply tweet by account "X".
- Account "X" uses the Twitter reply function to reply to its own tweet and adds "(This is a reply to URL)", where "URL" is the link to "Z's" tweet to which "K" replied.

At the end, the "AWS cache" is cleaned up to delete media and data that is no longer needed so as not to burden the limited storage space of the free account.

---

The AI's script* seems to reach the limits of free usage by "class MyStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener)" on the part of Twitter if I understand correctly?! Since AI is failing to help me, I'm asking you guys.

Is it even possible to use this Twitterbot in the free AWS and Twitter-Develper edition? Could the "MyStreamListener" maybe be bypassed or so per other or better code? Thank you!

*here the final ai script:

```
    import tweepy
import boto3
import requests

# Twitter API-Daten
twitter_api_key = "x"
twitter_api_secret = "xx"
twitter_access_token = "x-x"
twitter_access_token_secret = "x"

# AWS API-Daten
aws_access_key = "x"
aws_secret_access_key = "xx"
aws_region = "us-east-1"

# Twitter OAuth-Authentifizierung
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(twitter_api_key, twitter_api_secret)
auth.set_access_token(twitter_access_token, twitter_access_token_secret)

# Erstellen des API-Clients für Twitter
twitter_api = tweepy.API(auth)

# Erstellen des Boto3-Clients für AWS S3
s3_client = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id=aws_access_key, aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret_access_key, region_name=aws_region)

# Funktion zum Hochladen von Medien auf AWS S3
def upload_media_to_s3(url, media_type):
    response = requests.get(url)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        media_data = response.content
        media_key = f"media/{media_type}"
        s3_client.put_object(Body=media_data, Bucket="kimdotbucket", Key=media_key)  # Bucket-Namen hier einfügen
        return f"s3://kimdotbucket/{media_key}"  # Bucket-Namen hier einfügen
    return None

# Twitter-Account von "@KimDotcom"
k_username = "@KimDotcom"

class MyStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
    def on_status(self, status):
        # Wenn ein neuer Tweet von "@KimDotcom" empfangen wird
        if status.user.screen_name.lower() == k_username.lower():
            tweet_text = status.text
            tweet_id = status.id
            
            # Prüfe, ob der Tweet ein Bild enthält
            if 'Bild' in tweet_text:
                # Extrahiere den Bild-Link
                image_url = tweet_text.split('Bild: ')[1].split()[0]
                
                # Lade das Bild auf AWS S3 hoch
                media_url = upload_media_to_s3(image_url, 'image')
                
                if media_url:
                    # Tweete die Antwort mit dem hochgeladenen Bild
                    response = f"@{k_username} Vielen Dank für das Bild! Hier ist der Link: {media_url}"
                    twitter_api.update_status(response, in_reply_to_status_id=tweet_id)
            
            # Prüfe, ob der Tweet einen Video-Link enthält
            if 'Video' in tweet_text:
                # Extrahiere den Video-Link
                video_url = tweet_text.split('Video: ')[1].split()[0]
                
                # Lade das Video auf AWS S3 hoch
                media_url = upload_media_to_s3(video_url, 'video')
                
                if media_url:
                    # Tweete die Antwort mit dem hochgeladenen Video
                    response = f"@{k_username} Vielen Dank für das Video! Hier ist der Link: {media_url}"
                    twitter_api.update_status(response, in_reply_to_status_id=tweet_id)

# Erstellen einer Instanz des Stream Listeners
my_stream_listener = MyStreamListener()

# Erstellen des Streams und Filtern nach dem Benutzer von "@KimDotcom"
my_stream = tweepy.Stream(auth=twitter_api.auth, listener=my_stream_listener)
my_stream.filter(follow=[twitter_api.get_user(k_username).id_str])

# ...
# Rest des Codes für das Überprüfen des AWS-Kontingents, Ausführen des Bots und Löschen der Dateien
# ...



# Funktion zum Verarbeiten der empfangenen Tweets
def process_tweet(tweet):
    tweet_text = tweet.text
    user_screen_name = tweet.user.screen_name
    tweet_id = tweet.id
    
    # Prüfe, ob der Tweet ein Bild enthält
    if 'Bild' in tweet_text:
        # Extrahiere den Bild-Link
        image_url = tweet_text.split('Bild: ')[1].split()[0]
        
        # Lade das Bild auf AWS S3 hoch
        media_url = upload_media_to_s3(image_url, 'image')
        
        if media_url:
            # Tweete die Antwort mit dem hochgeladenen Bild
            response = f"@{user_screen_name} Vielen Dank für das Bild! Hier ist der Link: {media_url}"
            twitter_api.update_status(response, in_reply_to_status_id=tweet_id)
    
    # Prüfe, ob der Tweet einen Video-Link enthält
    if 'Video' in tweet_text:
        # Extrahiere den Video-Link
        video_url = tweet_text.split('Video: ')[1].split()[0]
        
        # Lade das Video auf AWS S3 hoch
        media_url = upload_media_to_s3(video_url, 'video')
        
        if media_url:
            # Tweete die Antwort mit dem hochgeladenen Video
            response = f"@{user_screen_name} Vielen Dank für das Video! Hier ist der Link: {media_url}"
            twitter_api.update_status(response, in_reply_to_status_id=tweet_id)


# Funktion zum Verarbeiten der empfangenen Tweets
def process_tweet(tweet):
    tweet_text = tweet.text
    user_screen_name = tweet.user.screen_name
    tweet_id = tweet.id
    
    # Prüfe, ob der Tweet ein Bild enthält
    if 'Bild' in tweet_text:
        # Extrahiere den Bild-Link
        image_url = tweet_text.split('Bild: ')[1].split()[0]
        
        # Lade das Bild auf AWS S3 hoch
        media_url = upload_media_to_s3(image_url, 'image')
        
        if media_url:
            # Tweete die Antwort mit dem hochgeladenen Bild
            response = f"@{user_screen_name} Vielen Dank für das Bild! Hier ist der Link: {media_url}"
            twitter_api.update_status(response, in_reply_to_status_id=tweet_id)
    
    # Prüfe, ob der Tweet einen Video-Link enthält
    if 'Video' in tweet_text:
        # Extrahiere den Video-Link
        video_url = tweet_text.split('Video: ')[1].split()[0]
        
        # Lade das Video auf AWS S3 hoch
        media_url = upload_media_to_s3(video_url, 'video')
        
        if media_url:
            # Tweete die Antwort mit dem hochgeladenen Video
            response = f"@{user_screen_name} Vielen Dank für das Video! Hier ist der Link: {media_url}"
            twitter_api.update_status(response, in_reply_to_status_id=tweet_id)

# Starte den Stream und verarbeite die empfangenen Tweets
my_stream.filter(follow=[twitter_api.get_user(k_username).id_str])
for tweet in my_stream.listener:
    process_tweet(tweet)

# Funktion zum Überprüfen des AWS-Kontingents
def check_aws_quota():
    response = s3_client.get_account_quota()
    quota = response['Quota']
    usage = response['Usage']
    
    print(f"AWS S3 Kontingent:")
    print(f" - Belegter Speicher: {usage['TotalSize']} Bytes")
    print(f" - Gesamtspeicher: {quota['MaxSize']} Bytes")

# Funktion zum Ausführen des Bots
def run_bot():
    # Starte den Stream und verarbeite die empfangenen Tweets
    my_stream.filter(follow=[twitter_api.get_user(k_username).id_str])
    for tweet in my_stream.listener:
        process_tweet(tweet)

# Funktion zum Löschen der nicht mehr benötigten Dateien aus AWS S3
def delete_unused_files():
    response = s3_client.list_objects(Bucket='kimdotbucket')
    objects = response['Contents']
    
    for obj in objects:
        key = obj['Key']
        last_modified = obj['LastModified']
        age = datetime.datetime.now() - last_modified
        
        # Lösche Dateien, die älter als 7 Tage sind
        if age.days > 7:
            s3_client.delete_object(Bucket='kimdotbucket', Key=key)
            print(f"Datei {key} wurde gelöscht")

# Starte den Stream und verarbeite die empfangenen Tweets
my_stream.filter(follow=[twitter_api.get_user(k_username).id_str])
for tweet in my_stream.listener:
    process_tweet(tweet)

# Überprüfe das AWS-Kontingent
check_aws_quota()

# Führe den Bot aus
run_bot()

# Lösche nicht mehr benötigte Dateien aus AWS S3
delete_unused_files()
```